# How to count number of relations of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having problem wrapping my mind around something.
Let's assume set A = {1,2}. How many relations are there in the group?
I know there's a formula that goes $$2^{n^2}$$ where $n$ is the number of objects in a set. That gives us $$2^4$$ which is 16.

But when I count the relations manually:

{1,1}
{2,2}
{1,2}
{2,1}

That gives me only 4. What am I missing here?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What you manually counted there was the number of ordered pairs of a set (*and as a nitpick they should have been using parentheses, not brackets*).  The *relations* of a set will be the various possible *collections of* ordered pairs.  For example $\{(1,1),(1,2)\}$ is a relation.  So too is $\{(1,1)\}$ and so too is $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}$ etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you!

Comment: What group?????

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$R$ is a relation on set $A$ if and only if $R$ is a subset of $A\times A$.

Comment: Yes I understand the definition of R relation of A if and only if R is a subjet of A x A. I will assume again that A = {1, 2}. A x A gives us a new set that is of 4 elements. Doesn't that mean that the maximum elements of R relation of A needs to be 4?

Comment: @Enof the largest *cardinality* of a *specific single* relation will be $4$.  This is not what the question is asking.  It is not asking how many elements are possible to be *in* a relation.  It is asking how many *relations themselves* are possible.

Comment: @JMoravitz I feel dumb. Now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is set $A:=\{1, 2\}$.

This is an ordered pair: $(1,2)$

This is set $A\times A:=\{(1,1),\ (1,2),\ (2,1),\ (2,2)\}$.

A relation $R$ on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$, or equivalently, $R$ is a member of the power set of $A\times A$.

For a set $S$ of size $n$, the set $S\times S$ has size $n^2$, and the power set of $S\times S$ has $2^{n^2}$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\{1,2\}$$

$$A\times A=\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1)\}$$

$A\times A$ has $4$ elements. So total number of subsets of $A\times A$ is $2^4=16$. Each of the subset of $A\times A$ is a relation. They are
$$\emptyset,
\{(1,1)\},\{(2,2)\},\{(1,2)\},\{(2,1)\},\{(1,1),(2,2)\},
\{(1,1),(1,2)\},\{(1,1),(2,1)\},\{(2,2),(1,2)\},\{(2,2),(2,1)\},\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2)\},\{(1,1),(2,2),(2,1)\},\{(1,2),(2,1)\}\{(1,1),(2,1),(1,2)\},\{(2,2),(2,1),(1,2)\},A.$$